# How can I have a systemd script wait enough to check a connection to the internet?

Tags: networking, systemd, internet

I've got a script that I've made into a oneshot systemd service. This runs on a raspberry pi and the point is that if it cannot connect to the internet it reconfigures the wifi adapter (?) to create an ad hoc network and reboots.

The problem I'm experiencing is that when it checks it hasn't yet received an IP address and thus thinks that it cannot connect.

I tried using the `After=` parameter to be `network-online.target` but that didn't change anything and I tried introducing a `sleep` command in the script itself but again no change.

Any ideas?

This is the script `check_connection.sh`:

```
INTERFACE_NAME=$(iwconfig 2>/dev/null | grep -o "^\w*")

sleep 5;

if ifconfig $INTERFACE_NAME | grep -q "inet addr"
then
    echo 'connected'
    # if connected check if it's ad hoc mode or not
    if iwconfig $INTERFACE_NAME | grep -q "Mode:Ad-Hoc"
    then
        echo 'start dhcp server'
        # if running in ad hoc mode make sure server starts
        sudo service isc-dhcp-server start
    fi
else
    echo 'not connected'
    # if not connected switch settings to ad hoc and reboot
    sudo cp /etc/network/interfaces-adhoc /etc/network/interfaces
    sudo reboot
fi
```

/etc/systemd/system/check_connection.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Check whether connected at startup
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/check_connection.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**EDIT**

The OS I'm running is: `Linux raspberrypi 4.1.7+ #817 PREEMPT Sat Sep 19 15:25:36 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux`

Comment: What is `systemctl list-dependencies network-online.target` giving you?

Comment: Not that much... it just prints `network-online.target`

Comment: What distribution are you using? Are you using NetworkManager?

Comment: Linux raspberrypi 4.1.7+ #817 PREEMPT Sat Sep 19 15:25:36 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux, I don't think I'm using NetworkManager, is there a way to check?

Comment: `NetworkManager` process should be running.

Otherwise, what is the version of the installed `ifupdown` package?

Comment: `-bash: NetworkManager: command not found` and `ps -ef | grep NetworkManager` doesn't return anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50334/discussion-between-evan54-and-bigon).

Comment: ifup version 0.7.53.1
Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Anthony Towns
Copyright (c) 2010-2013 Andrew Shadura

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution would be to update the `ifupdown` package to an higher version (>= 0.8.9) by using the debian backports (I *think* this should work on raspberian), have a look at https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/. You then need to update the `ifupdown` package.

What's happening here is that the `network-online.target` is not pulling any service and this means that it is considered "started" without actually waiting for anything. With the newer version of `ifupdown` the `networking.service` file contains the following lines, the means that it will cause the `network-online.target` to wait until it is fully started:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

EDIT: An other option could be to use the `After=networking.service` instead